# Skip terragrunt info output

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

No matter what `terragrunt` command I execute, it always starts with the following lines:

```
$ terragrunt show --json outfile 2>/dev/null
[INFO] Getting version from tgenv-version-name
[INFO] TGENV_VERSION is 0.31.10
```

```
$ terragrunt terragrunt-log-level=error plan
[INFO] Getting version from tgenv-version-name
[INFO] TGENV_VERSION is 0.31.10
```

I assumed that setting log level to `error` would perhaps help skipping those 2 lines.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need to remove these lines?

Comment: for several reasons; it makes my `json` parsing harder in the first example to begin with; the question is why are (should) they be so indispensable / mandatory? why not making it easy to skip them? (perhaps it is and I am missing the option)

Comment: Could you explain what kind of json? Are these `outputs` in json?

Comment: For example when running `tg state pull > mystate.json`, I want a pure json output to parse. These lines seem to break the `json` formatting

Comment: All the log is stderr, so `2>/dev/null` should work. Since logs are in stderr, `tg state pull > mystate.json` shoudl work as expected and you should get pure json in the file.

Comment: How did it go? Did you double check `2>/dev/null`?

Comment: yes that didn't work either; turns out it is an [issue](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1883) of `tgenv` I used to install `terragrunt`

Comment: FWIW you can try [`tgswitch`](https://warrensbox.github.io/tgswitch/) or [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/) in place of `tgenv` which seems to be abandonware.